# How to store a matrix of values in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, matrix

My requirement is to create a datastructure in which I can save boolean values based on a number of keys.
for example:

```
     |Mode|Code|Priority|
Name1|    |    |        |
Name2|    |    |        |
Name3|    |    |        |
Name4|    |    |        |
```

So that whenever I need the boolean value, I pass Mode, Code, Priority and Name and my datastructure returns the boolean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how a 2d matrix passing in Mode Code Priority and Name resolves to 1 bool - can you clarify? Or is that a 4d matrix?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a `Dictionary` whose keys are a custom type encoding the mode, code, priority, and name and whose values are `bool`s indicating the value you're storing.  If your values are predominantly `false`, then you could instead use some sort of hash set that stores tuples associated with `true` where all values not present in the set are implicitly missing.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: `Dictionary<Name,MagicalClass>`

Option 2: `[int][int]`

But what you are looking for is clearly the Dictionary and not a matrix.